# epsilon ball on a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

function g belongs to Banach Space, (g ∈ B([0,1],$\mathbb{R}$)) be defined by $g(x) = 0$ for all x ∈ [0,1]

and the problem ask me to find a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ in $V_{1}$[g] that is not a Cauchy sequence. $V_{1}$ represent epsilon neighborhood of radius 1.

The function I have come up with $f_{n}=-1^{n}$ for all n∈N.

Can anyone please check if it's correct? I'll be grateful.

Comment: What is "$B([0,1],\mathbb{R})$"?! Why is the $\LaTeX$ (MathJax, ok...) mixed with plain text?! What is $V_1[g]$?! What do you mean by "represent epsilon neighborhood of radius 1."?!

We don't know the notation that you're using in your course. Please give a few more details :)